# How to install mssql driver (sqlsrv)for Laravel in MAC?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

Im trying to connect to mssql server from My Mac OS. My application development OS is MAC.

I try to download the driver [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server), but it is not for MAC.

Can anyone shed some light on how to install the mssql driver for php/laravel in MAC?

Comment: You can try to download XAMPP and it will work. Download [Here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

Answer (score 2):

Follow this guide MS have put together to install the necessary dependencies to create PHP apps with SQL Server: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/mac/

If you have PEAR installed you can run the below command"

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo echo "extension= pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
sudo echo "extension= sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Change the default driver from mysql to

```
 'default' => 'sqlsrv',
```

In sqlsrv array provide the correct details to you sql IP

```
  'sqlsrv' => array(
   'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
   'host' => ' ip adress', 
   'database' => 'database',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => '',
   'prefix' => '',
  ),
```

You can also addition key values to array if you like.

[Found on](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/connect-laravel-to-microsoft-sql). Do you need help with this set up?

Comment: I changed like above databse.php file. but Im getting pdomssql-driver not found exception.

Comment: which version of php are you using?

Comment: version 7.1. I followed this guide https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql, and when try to run this command; #brew install microsoft/msodbcsql/msodbcsql , im getting some curl error  // odbcinst -i -d -f ./odbcinst.ini

odbcinst: SQLInstallDriverEx failed with Invalid install path.

If reporting this issue please do so to (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
microsoft/msodbcsql

/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/github.rb:226:in `raise_api_error': curl failed!  (GitHub::Error)
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 422 Unprocessable Entity
curl: (3) <url> malformed
//